# Error vs Fatal in tests

Tags: go

I am developing a JSON web service using [Go-Json-Rest](https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest). I am writing tests.

```
...
recorded = test.RunRequest(t, &api.Handler,
    test.MakeSimpleRequest("POST", "http://localhost/api/products",
        product))
recorded.CodeIs(201)
recorded.ContentTypeIsJson()

var newProduct Product
err := recorded.DecodeJsonPayload(&newProduct)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
...
```

I am using `Fatal` as I am coming from Python world where an `assert` would immediately stop test case method execution. And this make sense: why trying to decode the data, if it's not JSON?

But `recorded.CodeIs(201)`, `recorded.ContentTypeIsJson()` and other tests I've seen use `Error` which doesn't stop test execution.

What should I use in tests? `Error` or `Fatal`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you use `Error` until continuing to run the test can't possibly give you any more information useful in debugging, then you use `Fatal`. And if you're not sure (like if you're writing a factored-out method like `CodeIs` to be used in the context of lots of different tests), go for `Error`, since you're generally not doing *harm* by continuing to run the test.

By that criteria, it makes sense for you to `Fatal` at failed JSON decoding after which, as you say, nothing interesting is going to happen. And it's understandable that `CodeIs` and `ContentTypeIsJson` use `Error` because they're methods that are going to be used across different tests.

A different example might better illustrate why to use `Error` until you know nothing else interesting will happen: say you want to sanity-check several different things about the JSON response, and any subset them could be wrong. (Like, your product API could return `price` using the wrong type, or it could fail to return empty `description`s when you don't want that, or...) Using `Error` instead of `Fatal` for each check means your test will always run them all and report which ones failed.